# Problem handling user log out with the WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

I am working on a personnal project to power my DIY Ambilight setup ([Github repo](https://github.com/kevinpastor/ambilight-screen-grabber)). In summary, the program runs a series of command all the time and send it to an external Arduino board that then process everything. A final message should be sent to the board if the user where to lock his session or even log out. The problem I have is that I'm not able to handle the `WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE` message properly.

Any help could help at this point. `Ambilight::pause` should only temporary stop the execution while `Ambilight::stop` should completely end everything. I don't really know where the method `Ambilight::stop` should be called since this is my first project using the WinAPI. My algorithm is running in a separate thread; I think maybe this could be the issue. Here's the simplified code used to handle everything:

main.cpp

```
// ... global initializations

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    // ... other messages handling

    case WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE:
        // this case doesn't seem to work properly
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK:
            ambilight.start();
            break;

        case WTS_SESSION_LOCK:
            ambilight.pause();
            break;

        case WTS_SESSION_LOGOFF:
            ambilight.stop();
            break;
        }
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // ... hWnd Creation

    WTSRegisterSessionNotification(hWnd, NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION);

    ambilight.start();

    MSG message;
    while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }

    ambilight.stop();

    return (int)message.wParam;
}
```

Ambilight.cpp

```
#include "Ambilight.h"

Ambilight::Ambilight(const Options & options)
    : isPaused(true),
    isStopped(false),
    thread(&Ambilight::exec, this, options)
{ }

Ambilight::~Ambilight()
{
    this->stop();
}

void Ambilight::start()
{
    this->isPaused = false;
}

void Ambilight::pause()
{
    this->isPaused = true;
}

void Ambilight::stop()
{
    this->pause();
    this->isStopped = true;

    if (this->thread.joinable())
    {
        this->thread.join();
    }
}

void Ambilight::exec(const Options & options) const
{
    // .. action initialization

    bool hasFaded = false;
    while (!this->isStopped)
    {
        while (!this->isPaused)
        {
            // ... recurring action

            hasFaded = false;
        }

        if (!hasFaded)
        {
            // ... action that is supposed to be execute when user logs off

            hasFaded = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to run a message pump in a thread - any thread, and probably you need a hidden window handle to receive the messages. In WinApi, window handles often have nothing much to do with visible windows.

Comment: Narrow your problem down. Is it that you're not getting the messages you expect, or is it that once you've gotten those messages your thread isn't shutting down properly? If your thread isn't receiving messages you don't need a message pump or hidden window in it. You might also consider that you probably don't need a thread for this. In a small program like this the main thread spends a lot of time doing nothing. Switch to a PeekMessage pump and do your work in that idle time the main thread would be blocked waiting for messages.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817139/game-loop-in-win32-api